ROLLBACK in ORACLE fails
SELECT * FROM BOOKS;  -- 100 ROWS returned.  
DELETE FROM BOOKS;  -- 100 rows deleted  
SELECT * FROM BOOKS;  -- no rows returned.  
ROLLBACK; --Rollback complete.  
SELECT * FROM BOOKS;  -- no rows returned.

I expected that ROLLBACK would bring all the rows back and the last select statement will return 100 rows. But it returns no rows.
I am leaning SQL using ORACLE database. The rollback fails.

In which client/application? Are you perhaps executing each statement through a connection that is set to auto-commit? (Or, indeed, did you not commit the original insert…?)

were the inserts originally committed? rollback returns you to the start of the transaction, not to the start of the last SQL statement. In oracle, any DML will start a transaction and that will stay open until committed. A rollback will undo the work of everything from the start of the transaction.

It's most probably because you didn't commit the first insert of the 100 rows:
then when doing the rollback you are back to the situation before the insert.
Do: INSERT COMMIT DELETE ROLLBACK
and you will see back you 100 inserted rows.
